# Mongoose - populate(path, callback) vs populate(path).exec?

Tags: mongoose

The mongoose document of "Document.prototype.populate()" puzzled me! Based on the document link https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate, there mentioned as below image snapshot 
[image]

So, what is the different 
between 
populate(path).exec(function(err, result))
and 
populate(path, function(err, result))

Is it because the Model.findOne() cause this difference?
[image]

Comment: You're looking at `Document#populate` docs, but `.findOne()` returns a [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query) object, so you should refer to [Query#populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) docs instead. Two methods are almost identical, though.

Comment: Thank you @LeonidBeschastny. Thanks so much for your answer. I followed your instruction and finally understood the concepts of Query, Document, Model and their relationships.